# How can I update the roles for all logins using T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I need to update the roles for all database logins, but without using SQL Server Management Studio. I can update a single user with the following example SQL.

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_addsrvrolemember
    @loginame = N'User1',
    @rolename = N'dbcreator';
```

But how I can do this for all users? Is there a way to select the names of all the users and then loop through the list and update them all?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using ?

Comment: @KinShah SQL Server 2016 Express. I'm using OSQL to run the query.

Comment: At database level, you can play with sys.sysusers table: SELECT name, 'ALTER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER ' + name AS script FROM sys.sysusers WHERE issqluser=1 AND uid > 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql.

```
declare @sqltext nvarchar(max) = N''

-- here you are adding all the logins to dbcreator fixed server role ...
-- this is just an example to get you started ...adjust it as per your needs !!
select @sqltext += 'ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER '+QUOTENAME(name)+';'+char(10)+'go'+char(10) from sys.server_principals 
where type_desc ='SQL_LOGIN' -- only for sql logins 
and name <> 'sa' -- not sa
and name not like '##%' -- not special logins like certs etc 
and is_disabled = 0 -- not disabled 

print @sqltext 
--once you are fine with the output then uncomment below 
-- exec sp_executesql @sqltext -- this will actually run the sql !!
```

Comment: You'll have to copy and paste that script and run it, as it's a multi-batch script with `go`'s

Comment: Or you can just remove the batch separator `GO` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to build the script that you can then view and run separately.

```
select 
'ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [' + sl.loginname+ ']
GO
' as SQLCommand
from sys.syslogins sl
```

You can also modify the query to filter on database name `sl.dbname` or username `sl.loginname'

Execute each row in the output to add the users to the role.

Comment: why use `sys.syslogins` deprecated view from sql server 2000 ?

Comment: I didn't realise it was deprecated and it still works on my Azure Managed Instance 

Answer (score -1):

```sql
declare @w_cmd nvarchar(max), @w_login  nvarchar(30)
declare CursApp cursor for select name from master..syslogins where name like 'SRV%' for read only
open CursApp
while 1=1
begin
   fetch next from CursApp into @w_login
   if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 break
   set @w_cmd = 'ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER ['+@w_login+']'
   print @w_cmd
   exec sp_executesql @w_cmd 
end 
close CursApp
deallocate CursApp
GO
```